# create custom fileds in Article Manager of joomla 1.5

Tags: php, joomla1.5

I am beginner in joomla so For some customization in joomla's core files i am getting troubles.

what i want:- I want to add check box in article detail page.by using this option i will get the value that the current article should be "Latest or not".

what i done:-i added the extra 1 field of Boolean type in jos_content. and create a check box on article edit form.i create the check box in following code administrator/components/com_content/admin.content.html.php

```
<td>
                <label>
                <?php echo JText::_( 'Latest News' ); ?>
                </label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?php echo $lists['latestnews']; ?>
            </td>
```

My Question:- how can i add this field value and update in database?

i found to create such things for joomla 1.6,1.7.but the file structure of joomla 1.5 is very different to other versions.
Please help me out..Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to edit `controler` and `tables` which saves the data into database names must be something with article!